# Access combo box not changing default value

Tags: ms-access

I'm getting some odd behavior from a combo box which I am trying to change the default value of. Even if I remove "By Plant" from the row source it is still present as a default, though it does remove it from the drop down so I can't change back to it if I manually change it to "By Units". Obviously default value doesn't work. Show only row source also did nothing. The event procedure only updates the text boxes to the right.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a ResetForm function which hard coded the initial value to "By Plant". Changed that and it worked.